# Removing [ecmascript-6] tag from questions

Tags: discussion, tags, language-versions

I've seen a number of questions recently where the [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) tag has been removed from a question. I don't really want to name & shame anyone so I'll not post the links to the questions.

These mainly appear to be questions where the *root cause* of the problem was not due to ES6 syntax - but a problem with the logic in general (or a problem with syntax which was already available in <=ES5);

Shouldn't questions containing ES6 syntax be tagged as such, regardless of whether the root cause of the issue pertains to the ES6 syntax itself? If nothing else it may allow potential answerers to provide a better/more up-to-date answer to the question.

Comment: Imo: If it contains ES6 syntax, it should be tagged ES6. Otherwise, you may get comments saying the question contains invalid JS.

Comment: If the question doesn't have *anything* to do with ES6, then it doesn't need an ES6 tag.  If the OP is using code that wouldn't exist without the ES6 specification, I don't see the harm in including the tag, but it's not required unless the problem has specifically to do with ES6 features.

Comment: The code in the question *does* use ES6 syntax, so I guess your answer indicates that the tag shouldn't be removed.

Comment: Are you refering to the edits by @FelixKling and me, or is it someone else?

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: What about if OP is open to an ES6 answer but hasn't written any modern code?

Comment: @SterlingArcher If I was writing that question, I'd put an ES6 tag on it to make it immediately obvious that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Of course, as would I, but you can't always expect nooblets to tag a question properly. But at least answering an ES5 question with ES6 isn't frowned upon like answering with jQuery. *shudder*

Comment: My guess is that at some point in the future, maybe 5 years from now or so, the tag will become obsolete. Just like an "ES5" tag doesn't make much sense today.

Comment: @AwalGarg Most assuredly. Probably not even that far in the future. Having said that now that the ECMAScript spec is going to be updated on an annual basis, it might even be *more important* to keep separation between features which may exist now, but not next year or the year after.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the question doesn't have *anything* to do with ES6, then it doesn't need an ES6 tag.

If the OP is using code that wouldn't exist without the ES6 specification, I don't see the harm in including the tag, but it's not required unless the problem has specifically to do with ES6 features.

Don't remove ES6 tags from questions that contain ES6 code.

Answer (score -3):

> Shouldn't questions containing ES6 syntax be tagged as such, regardless of whether the root cause of the issue pertains to the ES6 syntax itself?

**No**. Not more than a question that contains code with an array literal should be tagged [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array).
Only questions that are specifically about new features or syntax should be tagged [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6), just like it is the case with the [ecmascript-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-5) tag (or any other language-version tags on SO). Tagging [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)is enough.

As @RobertHarvey said, there's no imminent harm (apart maybe from cluttering the ES6 activity feed). I have stopped myself a while ago from actively editing questions only to remove the tag (unless particularly inappropriate), but still when I (tag-)edit questions for other reasons I continue to remove it.

Comment: As Robert said: _"Don't remove ES6 tags from questions that contain ES6 code."_ What do you think about that?

Comment: I disagree with this. The reason we don't generally put explicit `ecmascript-5` tags is because it is supported by all major browser and is therefore inferred. Because ES6 is, to most people and implementations, *future* Javascript I feel there needs to be a disambiguation. The same logic would apply if I was using Node 5

Comment: @Cerbrus: As I said, if the tag is not appropriate I'll remove it. Just like this question is not also tagged with [meta-tag:questions], [meta-tag:edits], [meta-tag:code] or more. If someone is asking about jQuery selectors then that question only needs to be tagged "[tag:jquery] [tag:jquery-selectors]", even if he is using an arrow function somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating, @Bergi.

Comment: @RGraham: ES6 is, by the standard, *current* JavaScript. It's readily available to everyone who can run a transpiler like babel, and many features are supported in recent browsers. If someone uses an ES6 syntax, it can be as easily inferred that it's supported in his environment. Most recent [tag:javascript] questions (and older but actively maintained ones) are answered with ES6 versions if one of the "new" features is useful. The disambiguation happens in the answers.

Comment: @Bergi I understand that - I mean from users' perspective. It takes someone with knowledge of ES6 to spot the syntax. People may see `let` and say **that's not javascript, there's your problem**. Additionally, if the disambiguation was in the answer, what would stop me from leaving an ES7 answer? It's still javascript, but it's not relevant because the asker is specifically using ES6.

Comment: @RGraham "*what would stop me from leaving an ES7 answer?*" - Imo nothing - just clearly state it's ES7 ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28250697/1048572)). But yeah, tell that the guys who answer ES6 questions with everything that is available as an experimental babel plugin… (class properties being one of my pet peeves)

Comment: @RGraham: I have not yet found an occurence of "*that's not javascript, there's your problem*". Also you can tell them easily in the question text that you're "*using ES6 for brevity*" or something; this doesn't need to happen in the tags if the syntax is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for clarifying. I think I understand what you mean. I'm more convinced now about that usage of the ES6 tag, but I don't think enough that I would remove the tag myself personally.

Comment: @Bergi Does an opposing stance from a **moderator** not change your behavior? Are you going to continue doing this?

Comment: @Tyrsius Not agreeing or disagreeing with Bergi or Robert, but moderators are here to serve the community, not dictate its rules.  So the fact that it's an opposing stance by a moderator shouldn't come in to it - in that regard he's another individual, like everyone else here.  However, the relative voting on the two posts _by other community members_ should possibly be taken into account.

Comment: @JamesThorpe That's a good point, you are completely correct. I wonder if *that* changes his mind?

Comment: @Tyrsius: I don't think I disagree with Robert, we both think that "*the ES6 tag is not required unless the problem has specifically to do with ES6 features*". I tend to interpret the last sentence of his answer as "*Don't edit only to remove the tag*". I will continue to clean up tags (swap for better fitting ones) when editing questions, until being asked by a mod to stop. (Which has not yet happened, and an answer stating a different opinion doesn't overrule mine)

Comment: @Bergi do the community votes overrule yours? It seems pretty overwhelmingly against you.

Comment: @Tyrsius: This answer is quite controversial - I also got upvotes, and I'm not sure whether I should interpret downvotes as a vote to stop me (or whether they disagree on something else). None of the downvoters has left a comment with a convincing reason for me to stop (the discussion with RGraham was quite constructive).

Comment: @Bergi Roberts answer is not at all controversial, and states not to remove the tag. You've recieved twice as many downvotes as upvotes; not much of a controversy. Is this a moot point, or is their some vote distribution that *would* change your behavior?

Comment: @Tyrsius: Does it really matter that much, do you think I'm harming anything? As [one the top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ecmascript-6/topusers) we're just trying to keep the scope of the tag clean (I've seen such edits from both Felix and Benjamin as well). I'm not putting any active effort on it, but just try to do my best when I come across a question that needs an edit anyway.

Comment: @Bergi I think it matters enough to talk about it, that's the whole point of meta. I think it matters enough for the community to vote on two different stances. I think the community's stance should have some impact on our behavior, that's the whole point of the discussion. But I guess if you think none of it matters and you're just going to do whatever you want, regardless, then it doesn't matter. If it doesn't matter though, why spend so long talking about it?

Comment: @Tyrsius: That's what I wonder indeed. Do you have any additional points to make besides vote counts?

Comment: Yea, I don't think being a top site user gives anyone the right to ignore the community and do whatever they please.

Comment: @Tyrsius: I didn't mean to imply that I have "achieved any rights", but only to show that I am part of the ES6 community. Get someone else who is active in the tag asking me explicitly to stop, and I'll be happy to do it.

Comment: I don't see how a downvote on an answer on meta isn't exactly that. Meta is a site to discuss how we should act as a community, and up/down votes are literally *votes on what is right and wrong*.