# How should we tag and maintain questions about specific / upcoming ECMAScript features / problems?

Tags: discussion, tags, language-versions

There are more and more questions being about upcoming features in ECMAScript (class properties, decorators, etc). Many of these questions are tagged with [ecmascript-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-7), some even with [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6).

None of these tags really fit. ES2016 (ES7) is going to be finalized soon and it will most likely only add two features to the language (anything that is stage 4).

I can understand that not everybody follows the committee so closely to know which features will make it into the next version and which won't. <del>However, it seems we have a tag for planned features: [ecmascript-harmony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-harmony).</del> After reaching out some people on the TC39 committee, it seems they are using the term "es-next" to refer to upcoming features that are not scheduled for a specific revision yet. So I'd propose to introduce the tag [ecmascript-next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-next).

I would like to see us be more disciplined and organized in our tagging:

- [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript): Any question that is about JavaScript
- [ecmascript-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-5): Questions about features or problems that are specific or limited to ECMAScript 5 (*****)
- [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6): Questions about features or problems that are specific or limited to ECMAScript 6 (ES2015)
- [ecmascript-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-7): Questions about features or problems that are specific or limited to ECMAScript 7 (ES2016)
- etc...
- <del>[ecmascript-harmony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-harmony)</del>[ecmascript-next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-next): Questions about planned features (stages 0 - 3 at this point) (this means that many questions currently tagged with [ecmascript-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-7) need to be retagged).

Part of this effort will also be to keep tag descriptions and wikis up-to-date (even though it seems nobody reads them).

The problem of course is that as more and more environments adapt newer features, the newer features become standard. Planned features become part of released versions, etc. So:

- How should we tag questions when we are in a transition period to a new version?
- Should we retag questions (remove harmony, add version specific tag) if planned features become definite part of a version?
- Should we retag questions (remove the version specific tag) if that feature becomes supported by all major environments (and which one are those)?

All these seem to require some non-trivial amount of maintenance, probably to a degree where one might ask "is this even worth it?"

However, I think that correct tagging not only contributes to the "health" of the question ecosystem, but also contributes to educating others about ECMAScript. I'm not necessarily proposing that periodically sweep through tags to clean them up, but if we could at least agree upon a tagging "procedure" we can apply this when we come across such questions.

Some related questions:

- [What's the proper procedure when finding a synonym for a version specific tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317305/218196)
- [Removing [ecmascript-6] tag from questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311946/218196)
- [Retag ecmascript-harmony into ecmascript-6?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283398/218196)

---

*****: My personal opinion is that *usage* of features of a specific version alone doesn't warrant tagging the question with the correspond tag. E.g. if someone uses an arrow function, but the problem/question is about how to access object properties, it should not be tagged with [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6). But this needs to be decided individually for each question (and might be more difficult in transition periods like we are currently in).

Ideally, questions about generic problems (i.e. not about language features) (which of there are plenty) wouldn't even need version specific tags. There should be better support for answers that target different language versions. Imagine answers could be grouped by language version and were ranked only within their group (this would be my [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)).

Comment: Close all questions that are speculative in nature?

Comment: Are people even using the "harmony" nomenclature these days?

Comment: @torazaburo: apparently not. I asked on Twitter and Brendan and others are calling it "es-next". I will update my post soon, I guess we should have "ecmascript-next".

Comment: I started tagging questions with [tag:ecmascript-next] because apparently nobody cares deeply enough to object :P

Comment: @canon: that's one of the questions I'm asking :) I think this could be a lot easier if questions wouldn't be version specific, but answers, and there would be a better way to surface and reward version specific answers.